# How do I move an image from the top of the screen to the bottom and have it stay there in Xcode / iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying to build an entry effect for a logo to come from the top of the screen to the bottom and remain there when a new view loads in my application.  I have seen all of the tutorials that use NSTimer to bounce an image but once my logo hits the bottom it needs to exit.  I'm going to read up on animation block codes to see if my solution resides there.

Apologies I'm a new be and am very grateful for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set logo frame to top and then:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"moveLogo" context: nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
logoToMove.frame =  CGRectMake( final frame at the bottom );
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

`logoToMove` is your logo, give it an outlet and hook it in xib.
So you will set the initial frame and in the animation - the final frame. The animation will do the rest of the job.
Change `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` to a desired one if you don't like that. Also the duration to speed up or slow down the movement.

Comment: Great advice - thank you very much.
I'm trying to figure out the correct parameters in the CGRectMake (assuming that CGRectMake (10,10,300,400) means that I start at the upper left hand side of the iOS device screen, move to the right 10, move down 10 (start point for the rectangle) - then move over 300 to the right and 400 down to the bottom and that is the opposite corner making the full rectangle.  I've seen odd animation moves up sometimes, moves down sometimes... going to try UIViewAnimationCurveLinear to something else.  Thanks again!

Comment: Follow-up question for you Teodor - to set the initial frame would I do that in the Interface Builder or in code ?  if in code would I use something like logoToMove.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height ??

Comment: Guys, it's easier than you think. First set the frame programmatically wherever you want, this will be the starting point. Then use the code above to make the object move to the final point ( that you define in the 5th line: logoToMove.frame = bla-bla-bla ). That's all. And user1514009, you should read a bit about CGRectMake.

Comment: Thanks Teodor - I had made my initial frame the incorrect size - working great now - thanks again for your sage advice !!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the view at the end of your animation, the easiest way would be to use blocks :

```
logoToMove.frame = topRect;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration 
                 animations:^{
                    logoToMove.frame = bottomFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [logoToMove removeFromSuperview];
                 }
];
```

Doing it like that gives you control over the animation and on what to do once it's finished in a single method